# AWS SQS: Is it a way SQS call me consumer, every time a messages is pushed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Is there a way by which AWS SQS can call my REST API? Basically as soon as message is pushed to AWS SQS, I want to hear it and perform required action. I can schedule a listener that can pull messages every second but that won't be an optimizes solution and also the queue might be empty(sometimes).

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

**Use Publisher/Subscriber**

Look into using a publisher-subscriber model with SNS/SQS, so that you publish a message to SNS and subscribe to it via SQS. If you absolutely need to handle a message as soon as it is published, you can publish to SNS and set another consumer in addition to your SQS subscription (such as a [lambda subscriber](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html) that calls your Rest API?) to process it instead.

**SQS Long Polling**

Regarding SQS, it sounds like you would benefit from long polling.  From the documentation:

> Long polling helps reduce your cost of using Amazon SQS by reducing
>   the number of empty responses (when there are no messages available to
>   return in reply to a ReceiveMessage request sent to an Amazon SQS
>   queue) and eliminating false empty responses (when messages are
>   available in the queue but aren't included in the response):
>
> - Long polling reduces the number of empty responses by allowing Amazon
>     SQS to wait until a message is available in the queue before sending a
>     response. Unless the connection times out, the response to the
>     ReceiveMessage request contains at least one of the available
>     messages, up to the maximum number of messages specified in the
>     ReceiveMessage action.
> - Long polling eliminates false empty responses by querying all (rather than a limited number) of the servers.
> - Long polling returns messages as soon any message becomes available.

Also from the documentation, to enable long polling programmatically, use the following for any of these SQS actions:

- [ReceiveMessage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html): WaitTimeSeconds parameter
- [CreateQueue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html): ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds attribute
- [SetQueueAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html): ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds attribute

**Reference:**

- [Publish–subscribe (PubSub) Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)
- [SQS Documentation - Long Polling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would be much better of using SNS instead of SQS. What you are trying to get SQS to do, SNS was designed to do:

> You can use Amazon SNS to send notification messages to one or more
>   HTTP or HTTPS endpoints. When you subscribe an endpoint to a topic,
>   you can publish a notification to the topic and Amazon SNS sends an
>   HTTP POST request delivering the contents of the notification to the
>   subscribed endpoint. When you subscribe the endpoint, you select
>   whether Amazon SNS uses HTTP or HTTPS to send the POST request to the
>   endpoint. If you use HTTPS, then you can take advantage of the support
>   in Amazon SNS for the following...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html